# values in arithmatic in Ruby

Tags: ruby, math

I'm new to Ruby. I'm wondering what the values of `a` and `b` at `binding.pry`.
The value of `a` is nil, and the value of `b` is 11. Am I correct?

```
a = true
if !a
  b = 23
else
  b = 11
end
binding.pry
```

Comment: Why would `a` be nil after explicitly being assigned the value `true` ?

Comment: @mcfinnigan: I wasn't sure. so the value should be `true` then?

Comment: If you are using Pry, why don't you just type everything beside `binding.pry` to the Pry session? You can check variables like this: `a` or `b`. If you need something more, you can check this 3 sites: http://yorickpeterse.com/articles/debugging-with-pry/ https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger https://github.com/pry/pry-stack_explorer (You may need to install that gems: pry-debugger and pry-stack-explorer). If you want something easy, you can just put `puts a`, `puts b` etc. Or, instead of `puts`, use `p` (`p a`) it may print more info.

Answer (score 1):

`a` will be `true` and `b` will be `11`

why dont you open a ruby console and paste the code and try there itself??

Comment: I would argue that `b` is out of scope.

Comment: @BroiSatse [You'd be wrong](http://codepad.org/l5YVPURT). You seem to assume a combination of strict block scoping and implicit non-hoisted variable declaration that Ruby doesn't have.

Comment: @delnan - I am always happy to be proven wrong. :) Thanks

Comment: @shajin, @BroiSatse and @delnan: I ran ruby and `puts a` and `puts b` and it tells me that `a` is `false` and `b` is `true`. Anyone knows why is that?

Comment: @progresser Presumably because you did something wrong ;-) For example, ran a subtly different piece of code, or *also* ran other code that affected the result.

Answer (score 0):

`a` will be a `true` and `b` will be a `11`. Why?

You set it to the `true`:

```
a = true
```

You didn’t modify `a`.

```
!a
```

Doesn't modify `a`.

`!a` is *changed* to the `!true`, and that evaluates to the `false`.
A condition in the `if` is `false` so it takes `else`’s route.

Comment: @arup-rakshit Sorry, I forgot to delete that code.